# Is this differential equation exact?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The definition of exact differential equation reads that: "A differential equation of the form $M(x, y)dx+N(x, y)dy=0$ is said to be exact if its left hand member is the exact differential of some function say, $u(x, y)$ ..."

I came across a question like the following:

${(1 + 2xy cosx^2 - 2xy)dx + (sinx^2 - x^2)dy = 0}$

Here the M is a function of $x$ and $y$ but the N is a function of $x$ only as it appears. So, why does this qualifies as an exact differential equation?

Comment: Hint: $2xy\,dx + x^2\,dy = 0$ is exact.  What is $u$?  Now: is there any reason why $N$ should necessarily have to involve $y$?

Comment: According to the exact form it appears $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ as there should be a $y$ too. Why is the form written like so if it doesn't necessarily the case?

Comment: $N(x,y)$ means the function *can* depend on both x and y.  It doesn't mean it *has* to.  Just like we talk about the constant function $f(x)=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An differential equation defined as: $$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$$ Is exact if: $$\frac{\delta M}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta N}{\delta x}$$ Here $\delta$ represents partial differentiation - meaning differentiation of the term in the numerator with respect to the term in the denominator considering all other variables as constants. So in your case: $$M = 1 + 2xy\cos{x^2} - 2xy$$ and $$N = \sin{x^2} - x^2$$

Now using the condition for an exact differential equation:
$$\frac{\delta M}{\delta y} = 2x \cos{x^2} - 2x$$
$$\frac{\delta N}{\delta x} = 2x \cos{x^2} - 2x$$

As the two are equal, the equation is an exact differential equation.

Comment: Why doesn't $N$ matches the pattern $N(x,y)dy$ given in the form? It doesn't have a $y$ so why write it as $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$?

Comment: It does, it's just hidden. Consider $N = y^0 \sin x^2 - y^0x^2$.

Comment: We write it as a function of $x$ and $y$ in order to generalize the form.